# PHP + Linux Authentication

Tags: php, linux, apache, pam

I have a PHP script in Apache Web Server (on Centos 6.5).

I want to create directories and files with an user different from "apache" user.

I have tried to authenticate to linux machine with PAM from PHP script, but I can't. I have thought to use chown PHP function, but I think it's unuseful because I have to do this each time I create a file or something similar.

How can I face this problem? Is it possible?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Create a [group](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups#Group_management) and `chown` the directories `chown -R apache:mygroup .`

Comment: With this solution files created with PHP script will follow being owned by apache user.

Is there any form for making any action from PHP script always with the user which I want?

My situationis a login.php and then an upload.php. All what upload.php do has to be owned by user logged in. In concrete, upload a file to the Apache Server.